rstudio rticles/elsearticle template fails when knitting
when I create a new template with elsevier journal article the knitting fails with the following:
> The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
> I couldn't open style file elsarticle-harv.bst
> 
> 
>  \---line 5 of file test.aux
> : \\bibstyle{elsarticle-harv
> :                          }
> I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
> I found no style file---while reading file test.aux
> (There were 2 error messages)
> tlmgr update --all --self
> tlmgr install elsarticle
> tlmgr.pl: package repository https://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: pubkey missing)
> tlmgr.pl install: package already present: elsarticle
> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2024)
> The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
> I couldn't open style file elsarticle-harv.bst
> 

and then lots more errors and failing with execution halted
I have installed latest rticles from github. Still same issue. I cannot find elsarticle-harv.bst
anywhere in /library/rticles/rmarkdown/templates/elsevier.
This is since updating to R4.4.0. it used to work under previous versions.

In this {rticles} issue, one person managed to solve this error by running tinytex::install_tinytex().
